# Can I use pin-held V-Brake inserts in (cantilever) screw-held Shimano M Type brake pad holders?

Tags: brake-pads, rim-brake

I have 1990s Shiman Deore XT cantilever brake pad holder shoes with smooth studs.  I believe these are "M Type" cartridges/inserts. The replaceable inserts slide in and are held in place by a screw / grub. They look like this:

[image: Shiman Deore XT brake pads]

I need to replace the replaceable inserts. However, I am having a hard time finding replacement inserts.

Is it possible to slide in "V brake" inserts that are readily available as replacement inserts?  For example, could I use the following inserts in the shoes shown above?

[image: Kool Stop V type refill insert]

Or, are there any other inserts that can work with the Deore XT brake shoes that I have?  As a side note, there is corroboration  that aftermarket replacements for my brake shoes are hard or impossible to find (see [here](http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=258466) and [here](http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=287271), e.g.).

Comment: The best option is to just go with normal (non-replacable insert) brake pads+shoes - these things are hard to find, and even if you do find them, theres a decent chance the rubber is not in good condition due to age.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the v-brake replacements fit in. However, normal cantilever brake pads are very easy to find. When you don't find a replacement insert, just order some entire brake pads. You will probably get just as good braking pads for the same price.

Edit: Perhaps ask these guys: http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/brakeshoes.html#dura.

Answer (score 0):

I lost a Shimano Deore Xl pad recently.

As a stop gap, with nothing else available - was in the middle of nowhere, I bought at Walmart some Bell brake pads ($4.99), which have screw posts. The post didn't fit perfectly (I only had to replace one brake pad) but once I tightened and adjusted, it worked great ... and still does.

This is for an old Gary Fisher MTB. I'm still looking for a replacement for the Shimano pads; I will likely have to replace the whole rig, however. But for now, that brake pad is solid and not going anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE]. I've reformatted your post to make it easier to read, but it still does not directly answer the question. I suggest you add a sentence like "Yes, you can." at the start of the post.